# Get the value and index of array attribute of xmlns data using postgresql query

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

```
<sample-test-data-history xmlns="dmotorworks.com/sample-test-data-history"> <payPaymentCode> 
<V Idx="1">CASH</V>
 </payPaymentCode>
 <StatusCode>C98</StatusCode> 
<Type> 
<V Idx="1">Cat</V> 
<V Idx="2">Mouse</V> 
<V Idx="3">Tree</V> 
</Type> 
<totMiscCost> 
<V Idx="1">100.00</V> 
<V Idx="2">150.00</V> 
<V Idx="3">200.00</V> 
</totMiscCost> 
</sample-test-data-history>
```

From this xmlns i need to get the idx value of the array for which the text is "cat" and based on that Idx value I need to get totMiscCost from the next array attribute with the same Idx value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xpath()` to use an XPath expression extracting parts of XML. It'll return an array of the matches, so you need to select the desired index if you want a scalar.

In the last, optional argument `xpath()` an array of arrays of to elements each can be given, that defines a namespace mapping.

In your case the XPath expression gets the text of `totMiscCost/V` where the value of the attribute `Idx` is equal to the value of the attribute with same name of `Type/V`. Note that you have to prefix the elements with the namespace alias.

```
SELECT (xpath('(//dns:totMiscCost/dns:V[@Idx=//dns:Type/dns:V[text()="Cat"]/@Idx]/text())[1]',
              nmuloc,
              ARRAY[ARRAY['dns',
                      'dmotorworks.com/sample-test-data-history']]))[1]
       FROM elbat;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=7b70c15c3e387dba955815feb5c05d28)

Comment: Returning Null values not the cost